# Send html structure in email script

Tags: php

How to send html structure in email php ? 
The code below print  a html structure as it is
 I want to send link

```
$email_message .= "<html><body><a href='http://www.rudraliving.com/brochure_images/$fname'>Download Attachment</a></body></a></html>"."\n\n";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are on localhost you should have to use phpmailer library or swiftmailer, for sending html mail you have to set html headers `"Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8"`
for example

```
<?php
$to = "somebodyelse@example.com";
$message .= "<html><body><a href='http://www.rudraliving.com/brochure_images/$fname'>Download Attachment</a></body></a></html>"."\n\n";>


// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// More headers
$headers .= 'Cc: myboss@example.com' . "\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

Comment: I am not on local host,I have uploaed on server

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**  [more info](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/23737696-How-do-I-send-with-PHPMailer-)

```
    <?php
    require 'class.phpmailer.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    //smtp start-----------------------(if u use smtp then uncomment following block)
   /* $mail->IsSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.mandrillapp.com';                 // Specify main and backup server
    $mail->Port = 587;                                    // Set the SMTP port
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'MANDRILL_USERNAME';                // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'MANDRILL_APIKEY';                  // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted
     */
    //smtp end-----------------------
    $mail->From = 'from@example.com';
    $mail->FromName = 'Your From name';
   //set to email
    $mail->AddAddress('ellen@example.com','to_name');               // Name is optional

    $mail->IsHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <strong>in bold!</strong>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
       echo 'Message could not be sent.';
       echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
       exit;
    }

    echo 'Message has been sent';
```